# Flutter: AppBar button with material page route not working properly on android, but works fine on web

Tags: flutter

I have this weird issue with buttons in the appbar not working on mobile but work fine on web version. I have two buttons: a settings button and logout button. I also have a tab controller. the tab controller works fine on both platforms.

Here's the code for the appBar.

```
String name = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.displayName.toString();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<GroupChannelState>();
    appState.init_groups_list();

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        bool wide_display = (constraints.maxWidth >= NARROW_SCREEN_WIDTH);
        if (wide_display) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text("Euphony"),
                actions: [
                  Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Welcome ' + name, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20), textAlign: TextAlign.center,)),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        
                        //print("Opened Settings Page");
                        debugPrintHitTestResults = true;
                    
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => settingsPage())));
                      },
                      child: const Icon(Icons.settings)
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        /*
                    print("Logged Out");
                    */
                        FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) {
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => LoginPage())));
                        });
                      },
                      child: const Icon(Icons.logout_outlined)
                  ),
                  
                ]
            ),
```

I don't receive any errors. the print statements never get printed either. Every time I press the buttons this is what I get.

```
D/EGL_emulation(13690): app_time_stats: avg=44.07ms min=1.15ms max=369.61ms count=22
D/EGL_emulation(13690): app_time_stats: avg=700.50ms min=0.86ms max=10325.35ms count=21
D/EGL_emulation(13690): app_time_stats: avg=578.28ms min=1.93ms max=8910.87ms count=16
D/EGL_emulation(13690): app_time_stats: avg=11.56ms min=1.46ms max=141.75ms count=52
D/EGL_emulation(13690): app_time_stats: avg=37.58ms min=13.05ms max=537.70ms count=40
D/EGL_emulation(13690): app_time_stats: avg=41.91ms min=12.88ms max=854.14ms count=33
D/EGL_emulation(13690): app_time_stats: avg=11.57ms min=1.48ms max=135.72ms count=52
```

I've tried breakpoints and print statements. They don't get reached.

Comment: I've also tried different flutter channels such as flutter channel main, master, and stable and have the same issues. Ive also ran flutter doctor -v and there are no issues found.

Comment: Please run `flutter doctor -v` and share result in your question.